# Will file pointer move with the change of file position?

Tags: c, file, pointers

When reading K&R, I became interested in how the file position is determined. By file position, I mean where in the file the stream is currently reading or writing. I think it must have something to do with the file pointer, or the piece of data it's pointing to. So I checked stack overflow, and find the following answer:

[Does fread move the file pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696845/does-fread-move-the-file-pointer)

The answer indicates that file pointer will change with the change of file position. This makes me very confused, because in my understanding, a file pointer for a certain file should always point to the same address, where information about this file is stored. So I wrote a small piece of code, trying to find the answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char s[1000];
    FILE *fp,*fp1,*fp2;
    fp = fopen("input","r");
    fp1 = fp; /* File poiter before fread */
    fread(s,sizeof(char),100,fp);
    fp2 = fp; /* File pointer after fread */
    printf("%d\n",(fp1 == fp2) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

It gives the output 1, which I believe indicates that the file pointer actually doesn't move and is still pointing to the same address. I have also changed the fread line to be a fseek, which gave the same output. So does file pointer move with the change of file position, or where am I wrong in the verifying process?

Thanks!

Comment: Nooo....  surely you understand that file systems require more than some pointer that moves to control access to a file!   The FILE* 'file pointer' is typically the base address of a file control block - a whole struct of metadata about the file.

Comment: you seem to be confusing the 'FILE * fp' that points (after a call to fopen()) to a 'file descriptor' control block to the data within the 'file descriptor' control block that indicates the current device, cylinder, track, sector, etc on the (in the general case) hard disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing the general concept of pointers in C, vs. the nomenclature of a "file pointer".  FILE is just a structure that contains most of the "housekeeping" attributes that the C stdio runtime library needs to interact with when using the stdio functions such as, fopen(), fread(), etc.  Here is an example of the structure:

```
typedef struct {
char *fpos; /* Current position of file pointer (absolute address) */
void *base; /* Pointer to the base of the file */
unsigned short handle; /* File handle */
short flags; /* Flags (see FileFlags) */
short unget; /* 1-byte buffer for ungetc (b15=1 if non-empty) */
unsigned long alloc; /* Number of currently allocated bytes for the file */
unsigned short buffincrement; /* Number of bytes allocated at once */
} FILE;
```

Note that this may be somewhat platform-dependent, so don't take it as gospel.  So when you call fopen(), the underlying library function interacts with the O/S's file system APIs and caches relevant information about the file, buffer allocation, etc, in this structure.  The fopen() function allocates memory for this structure, and then returns the address of that memory back to the caller in the form of a C Pointer.

Assigning the pointers values to another pointer has no effect on the attributes inside the FILE structure.  However, the FILE structure, internally, may have indexes or "pointers" to the underlying O/S file.  Hence, the confusion in terminology.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was also thinking that it might just be a problem of terminology. Your answer is so clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are right `fp` is never changed by `fread`, `fseek`or other `f...` functions. Except, of course, if you do `fp = fopen(...)`, but then you are assigning the return value of `fopen` to `fp` and then `fp` changes of course.

Remember, in C parameters are passed by value, so `fread` cannot change it's value.

But `fread` does change the internal structure `fp` points to.

Comment: And it's not even guaranteed to change the structure: Some implementation could just piggyback on a lower-level file API using POSIX-style file descriptors, and simply put only the descriptor in the structure (though it would probably be slow performance-wise).

Comment: Thanks. The "pass by value" comment is really convincing.

Answer (score 1):

You made some confusion between a **file pointer**, under common definition, and the **pointer in the file**.
Normally with the term **file pointer** we refer to a pointer to a **FILE** structure. That structure contains all variables necessary to manage file access. This structure is **created upon a successful opening of a file**, and remains the same (same address) for all the time until you `fclose()` the file (when became undefined).

Inside the FILE structure there are many pointers that points to the file block on disk and to the position inside the current record. These pointers, managed by file I/O routines, changes when file is accessed (read or write).
And these pointers are that to which the answer you cited refers.

Comment: So you mean the file position is determined by a pointer inside the FILE structure? But how can this work if there is only a descriptor? I mean if a file is opened with system call open() rather than library routine open, there is no such thing as a FILE structure. Under this circumstance, file position should still be determined and can be changed by function like lseek.

Comment: @AlbertZhou File control structures are many. A first level is in the OS driver to take care of use of disk raw blocks, the next level is in the filesystem driver where raw data is organized in directories and files. Above that there is the so called low-level I/O (and `open()` is a low level) that has its own control structures. Then there is the High level I/O that uses FILE structures. `fopen()` uses FILE structure, that use a low level I/O that use filesystem that use raw I/O. Life is not easy ;-)

Comment: @AlbertZhou I forget a file descriptor is an index to an array of file control structures used by low level I/O routines. So there is data there not only a 'descriptor'...